# How to Navigate to 2nd Url (angular7) after success login in 1st Url

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor, puppeteer

Can some one help me out.... how to navigate to angular7 page from the non-angular page by changing the url.

please find my code snippet below:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function getPic() {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless : false,
        args     : ['--window-size=1920,1080']
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    //1st url is non angular page
    await page.goto('https://LT.html', {
        waitUntil : 'networkidle2',
        timeout   : 3000000
    });

    await page.waitForSelector('#login-form #userInput');
    await page.click('#login-form #userInput');

    await page.type('#login-form #userInput', 'rkatkam');

    await page.waitForSelector('#login-form #passwordInput');
    await page.click('#login-form #passwordInput');

    await page.type('#login-form #passwordInput', 'cisco123');

    await page.waitForSelector('#login-wrapper > #login #login-button');

    await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation(),
        page.click('#login-wrapper > #login #login-button')
    ]);

    //now after getting the authentication success, i have to navigate to 2nd url (my actual application url
    // this is angular7 page. this page takes time to load by that time my script is timing out 
    //timeout 30000ms exceeded
    await page.goto('https://myactualapplication/', { //2nd url
        // networkIdleTimeout: 5000,
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2'  
    });

}

getPic();
```

Comment: can you go straight to ur app page without logging into 1st one? have you tried setting higher timeout?

Comment: we cannot go to app page without loggin... it will say, no Session..
yeah i tried below options

 await page.goto('https://myactualApplication/', {
      // networkIdleTimeout: 5000,
      // waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
      timeout: 5000000
  });


//  await page.goto('https://myactualApplication');
//  await page.goto('https://myactualApplication', {waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded'});
  //  await page.goto('https://myactualApplication', {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
  // await page.goto('https://myactualApplication', {waitUntil: 'load'});

Comment: also below i tried

await Promise.all([
    page.waitForNavigation(),
    page.goto('https://myactualApplication'),
    page.keyboard.down('Enter'),
    page.waitForSelector('iframe[viewui="ng6-iframe"]')
  ]);

Comment: Do you know if that page takes more than 30 seconds to load?

Comment: yeah more than 50s.. and for complete page load 1mins 20sec

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `page.setDefaultTimeout` "globally", after the `const page = await browser.newPage();` command. Like this:

```js
const page = await browser.newPage();

// add this line:
await page.setDefaultTimeout(5*60*1000); // 5 minutes in miliseconds

// rest of the code...
```

If your page takes more than 5 minutes, increase the timeout.

Also in your code there is "networkIdleTimeout". This has no effect to puppeteer, since it's not recognized.